# Dashlet memo pad

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

I'm sharing the administration of CiviCRM with 2 other people. I would like the capability to leave notes and reminders for the other admins on their dashboard. Does anyone know of an extension that provides memo pad/notes as a dashlet?

The CMS is Joomla so can't use an Drupal functions.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not assign activities to them with priority/scheduled dates?

Comment: I would like it to be more of a notice board that we can all see and use rather than task driven.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Dashlet Note: https://github.com/AlainBenbassat/eu.businessandcode.dashletnote

There's an editor to create/edit a note. That note is saved as a dashlet and can be added on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CiviAlert](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civialerts) extension, you can configure it per user as well.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had seen CiviAlert but the document I read said it was for Drupal which Is why I added details of our CMS. I'm installing it now to have a look.

Comment: Its matter of changing line here https://github.com/mr-vara/me.vara.civialerts/blob/f8177f814a6137f312d8c13186fbb443e4e2399a/api/v3/CiviAlerts.php#L7 to include support for Joomla or any other cms

Comment: I have tried CiviAlert but it doesn't quite fit what I want. I would need to change the way URLs are handled to match Joomla. It also seems to have problems as trying to delete an alert kills civi and drops me to Joomla. I think I will have a go at writing my own. Thanks for the suggestions.